# AttributeError at /products/1/buy/ 'OrderForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

Im trying to build a django form for placing orders in my ecommerce website. But, when I press the `Place Order` button, I get this traceback error:

```
Internal Server Error: /products/1/buy/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\apnibakery\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\apnibakery\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Django\apnibakery\bakery\apnibakeryy\views.py", line 33, in buy
    form.save()
AttributeError: 'OrderForm' object has no attribute 'save'
[07/Dec/2020 14:06:34] "POST /products/1/buy/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64996
```

Here is my `OrderForm`:

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    zip_code = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=6)
```

My view function that handles the orders:

```
def buy(request,id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    form = OrderForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Your order has been successfully placed!!")
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'product':product,
    }
    return render(request, 'buy_page.html',context)
```

I have never ran into this error before. Can someone help me out?

Comment: `OrderForm` is a `Form`, not a `ModelForm`, so it has no `.save()` method.

Comment: It is however unclear if you have an `Order` model, or how you will save the form.

Comment: I dont have an Order model. So how can I save the form?

Comment: well exactly what records, etc. should be created at the database? A form can not automagically guess that.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: All I want is an Order to be placed. Should I create and Order model for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225610/discussion-between-samyak-jain-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: Not per se. The question is: what does it mean to place an order: what should change in the state of the server?

Comment: By placing an order, the user is sending an email to me, which I am going to implement right after this issue is resolved. Right now, the user is not *actually* placing and order. This is just a basic functionality to test my app

Comment: then you should define a `def save(self):` method that sends the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Form` has no `.save()` method. It would be unclear what that would mean since a `Form` is for example not tailored towards a model. It thus can for example not create or update a record in the database.

You can however implement a `save()` method yourself. For example a method that will then send an email:

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):

    # …

    def save(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        # …
```

here `cleaned_data` is a dictionary that maps the names of the fields (`name`, `email`, etc.) to the corresponding values.

You thus can for example send a basic email with:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class OrderForm(forms.Form):

    # …

    def save(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        send_mail(
            'Your order',
            "The order with name {cleaned_data['name']} and zip {cleaned_data['zip']}",
            None,
            [cleaned_data['email']],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

For more information about sending emails, see the [section in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail).